# Use Azure Key Vault secret in Header section of Web Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've been provided with API Endpoint URL and api key. Naturally, I don't want to store the original key in production pipeline, therefore I've asked to store it into secret in KeyVault. They have done that and I got my KV - lets name this secret `API-KEY-sec`. I am `POST`ing the data, and in headers I want to pass two parameters - `Content-Type - application/json` and `Authorization - API-KEY-sec` value but I struggle to manage to pass it. Tried to set `https://[KeyVaultName].vault.azure.net/secrets/[SecretName]'` as variable and give it as dynamic content to header `Authorization` parameter but it didnt work out. Any tips how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Use Azure Key Vault secrets in pipeline activities you need to use web activity to fetch the secret and then use it in your required activity:

To achieve that to need to first allow the ADF to read secret from key vault.

- Copy the Managed Identity Application ID value from the data factory's properties and add the managed identity to Get and List secrets by opening the key vault access policies.
  [image]
  [image]
- Go to your secret in key vault and copy **Secret Identifier**.
  [image]
- Then in ADF take web activity get the secret value

```
URL:        [Your secret URI value]?api-version=7.0 
example:    https://uytrewg.vault.azure.net/secrets/keyname/version?api-version=7.0
Method:     GET
Authentication: System Assigned Managed Identity
Resource:   https://vault.azure.net
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Now, use this secret value as **@activity('Web1').output.value** in further activities

Comment: I don't have permission to look upon secrets. Do I have to tell them to provide me secret identifier? This secret identifier needs to be put into URL or only to the part of secret name?

Comment: yes you will need the secret identifier URL to access the value of secret.

Comment: Yeah, just read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities and know everything. Thanks